# Trying to write an in-place implementation of quicksort and I'm having trouble returning the sorted array

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I've tried writing an in-place quicksort and I'm unable to properly return the sorted array. Based on the output from the print statement, the algorithm does appear to be sorting the array but I can't seem to return the sorted array. I thought it would be sorting in place but it doesn't seem to be and I'm not sure how to correct this issue.

```
def quicksort(array):

    if len(array) <= 1:
        return 

    pivot = len(array) - 1
    i = 0

    while i < pivot:
        if array[i] > array[pivot]:
            if i == pivot - 1:
                array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
            
            array[pivot], array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[pivot]
            pivot -= 1
            array[i], array[pivot+1] = array[pivot+1], array[i]
        else:
            i += 1
        
    print(array)
    quicksort(array[:pivot])    # sorts lower
    quicksort(array[pivot:])    # sorts upper

    return array


test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print quicksort(test)
```

Comment: `array[:pivot]` and `array[pivot:]` are slices, which create new lists; they don't change the existing list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are slicing a `list`, which returns **a copy and not a view**. Thus each of your recursive call sort a copy and not the original list. I recommend you use a `numpy.array` as input to perform your quicksort in-place. Indeed (basic) slicing a `numpy.array` returns [**a view**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing). This is the python data structure that is the closest to a canonical array.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I wasn't aware of this. After modifying with numpy it works as I originally expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the recursive call `quicksort(array[:pivot])`, you don't pass the original list to `quicksort()`, but instead create a new list.

To avoid creating new lists, you can drop the slice syntax and instead pass array indices to your function:

```py
def quicksort(array, start, length):

    if length <= 1:
        return 

    pivot = start + length - 1
    i = start

    while i < pivot:
        if array[i] > array[pivot]:
            if i == pivot - 1:
                array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
            
            array[pivot], array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[pivot]
            pivot -= 1
            array[i], array[pivot+1] = array[pivot+1], array[i]
        else:
            i += 1
        
    print(array[start:start+length])
    quicksort(array, start, pivot-start)    # sorts lower
    quicksort(array, pivot, length-pivot)   # sorts upper

    return array


test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print quicksort(test, 0, len(test))
```

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense.